# How to make a cloned Windows drive bootable from new location

Tags: windows

I recently installed a larger HDD in my PC which is now the D: drive. My existing HDD where Windows is installed is the C: drive. I've created a new partition on the larger HDD (E:) and successfully cloned C: to E: however I'm struggling to figure out how to make this bootable.

I have a Gigabyte motherboard, and in the BIOS settings I've set the boot order to point to the new drive, however that is not sufficient.

I've seen some tips online that state that in Disk Management I need to make the new partition "active" -- this option is greyed out, and when using DISKPART to accomplish the same task, it states that this is because it is not an MBR volume.

The only tips I've found on how to convert this to an MBR volume point me to using the repair utility in Windows 7 -- when I access this and attempt to run the boot recovery, I get a message stating that the version of recovery does not match my version of Windows, this is the dead end I've reached.

I don't know if the MBR business is even necessary, just stating the steps I've taken. Ultimately what I'd like to do is boot Windows from the new E: partition on the new HDD. Any advice for where to begin?

[image: Screenshot of Disk Management]